# Using Google Map in asp.net mvc Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to integrate Google Map in Asp.net mvc Entity frame work. I want to pass latitude and longitude from controller to view based on the location searched criteria, that part is working but i don't know how to pass it to the Javascript section i.e. latitude and longitude dynamically based on the return value from the controller. Please help to sort out my problem..

HomeController.cs

```
       LocationDbEntities dbentity = new LocationDbEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int id = 2;
            var query = dbentity.LocationDetails.First(c => c.Id == id);
            return View("Index", query);
        }
```

Index View

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.LocationDetail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>@Model.Latitude </p>
<p>@Model.Longitude</p>

 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">  
 </div>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         initialize();
     });
     function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.897400, 77.519500),
             zoom: 10,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
       mapOptions);
         // create a marker  
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.9167, 79.8473);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             title: 'My Place'
         });
     }  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your JavaScript variables from your Model properties inside a script tag like this.

```
<script>
   var myLat = '@Model.Latitude';
   var myLong = '@Model.Longitude';
</script>
```